# Reset ascx User control using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am working on a asp.net web application where we have search page. On this search page we have around 37 search filter control. All Input controls are different types like some are text boxes, Dropdownlist (which filled from Database on page load), Radio buttons and check box list.
On right side of page we are showing results of that search with the help of Jquery and Ajax. Now I create a .ascx User Control for left side Search filter and put all the Search filter controls in that user control. This page works fine for me the only issue is I have on Reset Search button on that page (i.e. Inside my ascx control) and I have to clear all the search filter controls value on that buttons click event( remember I don't want to reload my page so i use Jquery).
On solution for is, i have to write code for all 37 controls to reset its value to default.
Is there any trick or idea to reset or reload my user control from Jquery without refreshing page.

Note : Remember I can't put Update panel on aspx page for some reason.

Please give me any idea.

Comment: have you tried `$('#form')[0].reset();` ??

Comment: @NileshKRathod: What you can do is by using jquery you can clear all the 37 controls of the form in the client click

Comment: Yes this is the last way to do. But any idea about clear all controls of ascx controls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use input type selector for minimal code ie. $(':input') will select all text box field. If you want to clear all controls on current form I have written a small plugin you can use it:

```
$.fn.clearForm = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        var type = this.type, tag = this.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (tag == 'form' || tag == 'div') 
            return $(':input', this).clearForm();
        if (type == 'text' || type == 'password' || tag == 'textarea')
            this.value = '';
        else if (type == 'checkbox' || type == 'radio')
            this.checked = false;
        else if (tag == 'select')
            this.selectedIndex = -1;
    });
};
```

Usage:

```
$('#divId').clearForm();
$('.div_class').clearForm();
$('form').clearForm();
```

Comment: how to call this function on my Reset button. I write this code on my aspx page but not able to call this code.

Comment: Call this method as a jquery selector like if you want to clear all element on form then  $('form').clearForm();

Comment: If you want to clear Elements of a div just change this line if (tag == 'form')  to  if (tag == 'form' || tag == 'div') and then call like  $('#DivId').clearForm();